# Access github Api without user Authentication

Tags: github, github-api, github-app, github-api-v4

I have usecase to check my remote github repo has latest release tag from my terminal tool but the tool doesn't need any user authentication for github access.

I don't want to store the pat token from my code, any other appoarch i can use to solve the probelm

Need solution to access the github api from the tool, the tool can be downloaded and run by all the user. but i donot want to get the user details to hit github api

Comment: The Approach i Found ,

https://docs.github.com/en/apps/creating-github-apps/authenticating-with-a-github-app/about-authentication-with-a-github-app